# Storing lots of duplicate strings. Looking for good hash function to save storage.

Tags: database, oracle

I am looking for a good hash function to save on storage space while storing a lot of duplicate strings in Database.

I have a DB where I have to store this
DATE RATE DESCRIPTION
xxx  yyyy zzzz

100s of Millions of rows; The description is max say 1K string. The description string has high repeat; I will get many duplicates. To avoid that much (wasted) storage we are thinking of doing this

Table 1
DATE RATE DESC_ID

Table 2
DESC_ID DESCRIPTION

Approach 1: DESC_ID == MD5 hash --> DB has primary key on DESCID; app generates the hash; DB writes are fast (that is what I am thinking)

Approach 2: DESC_ID == DB generated ID; the unique key has to be DESCRIPTION; DB writes might be slower than the above approach.

Question1: Should I stick with MD5 or are there better algos out there? Is it worthwhile to go to SHA-x functions for theoretically better collision avoidance, while taking a hit on extra storage an d compute time?

Question2. Should I consider going to approach 2?

Comment: Why would writes be slower with approach 2? With the first approach you have to hash your description then see if that ID exists via the PK; with the second you just directly see if the description exists via the UK. Am I missing something - surely avoiding the has is faster? If the performance is that critical maybe the storage overhead of the duplicate values is worth it anyway.

Comment: Alex, I am thinking that the second approach would be slow because UK checking a long string would be more costlier than PK check of 32 char string (the MD5 hash). I have not done an experiment to validate this.

Comment: I guess that might make sense if you're doing the hash outside the database. More about your set-up might be useful. How high is the repeat rate; is there a small-ish defined set of descriptions, or can you get anything and might have to create new look-up entries on the fly? Thinking maybe your application could cache the descriptions and IDs, maybe.